# Replacing i with increasing numbers

Tags: python

I'm brand new to python so I apologize in advance. I need help renaming hundreds of files.

Currently my files look like this:
SRR3521304001.fastq
SRR3521305001.fastq
SRR3521306001.fastq
...

I would like my files to be renamed into the following format:
SRR3521304_S(i)_L001_R1.fastq
SRR3521305_S(i)_L001_R1.fastq
SRR3521306_S(i)_L001_R1.fastq
...

I need i to be a number that starts at 1 and increases.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
import os

files = os.listdir('joined_reads')
i = 1

for file in files:
    name = file.replace('001.fastq','S{i}_L100_R1_001.fastq')
    os.system('cp,   joined_reads/' + file + ' new/' + name)
    i+=1
```

This gives me files that look like SRR3521304_S(i)_L001_R1.fastq. Can someone help me change the i to an increasing number?

Comment: Add an "f-string" like this: ```file.replace('001.fastq',f'S{i}_L100_R1_001.fastq')```. also you don't need a counter, you can see ```enumerate``` to skip ```i +=1``` part

Comment: Do you want to keep the original files (as suggested by your use of `cp` in the question), or are you happy for them to actually just be renamed?

Comment: Note that you can use the built-in `shutil` module and it's [`copy`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copy) function rather than having to use `os.system`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use `{i}` you need to use `f` before your string to format it accordingly. Also you could use enumerate with the start value at 1.

```py
import os

files = os.listdir('joined_reads')

for i, file in enumerate(files, 1):
    name = file.replace('001.fastq',f'S{i}_L100_R1_001.fastq')
    os.system('cp,   joined_reads/' + file + ' new/' + name)
```